# How to run commands in REMOTE machine with the subprocess approach using passwordless authentication in python3?

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess, python-3.6

I am trying to write a script which should perform some commands (defined by Payload) in a ssh enable remote computer. I want to have a passworless connection. So that I can use the public and private key authentication. I know how to do it in paramiko and its working. Is there any way to do it by subprocess and get the output? Is there any sample code for that?

My sample code is something like that. For example,  I want to execute more connection later on.

```
import subprocess
def __init__ (type, options):
    if type=="ssh":
        ssh(options)
    else if type="fsexec":
        fsexec(options)

def ssh(self, ip, user, sshkey_file, payload):
    try:
        command = "ssh "
        prog = subprocess.call(["ssh -i sshkey_file -t user@ip 'payload'"])
        print(prog)
        print("Returncode:", prog)

def fsexec(self, ip, user, sshkey_file, payload):
    try:
        command = "ssh "
        prog = subprocess.call(["fsexec  -t user@ip 'payload'"])
        print(prog)
        print("Returncode:", prog)
```

Comment: you could take a look at `subprocess.Popen` and `Popen.communicate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Paramiko library to log in with ssh and the keyfile.

I copied an exmaple from a gist (https://gist.github.com/batok/2352501):

```
import paramiko
k = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/Users/whatever/Downloads/mykey.pem")
c = paramiko.SSHClient()
c.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
print "connecting"
c.connect( hostname = "www.acme.com", username = "ubuntu", pkey = k )
print "connected"
commands = [ "/home/ubuntu/firstscript.sh", "/home/ubuntu/secondscript.sh" ]
for command in commands:
    print "Executing {}".format( command )
    stdin , stdout, stderr = c.exec_command(command)
    print stdout.read()
    print( "Errors")
    print stderr.read()
c.close()
```

Comment: I actually checked this example using paramiko and works fine.